# How can I determine if nohz=off (CentOS 6.4 64bit - Hyper-V)

Tags: grub, centos6.4

I've edited `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and added `nohz=off` to the command line of the default kernel.

I do not see any difference, kernel is compiled with 1000Hz, but when I test with the following tool:
http://www.advenage.com/topics/linux-timer-interrupt-frequency.php

It reports only about 500Hz interrupt frequency.

`dmesg | grep nohz` only shows the kernel boot command.